# Can you even test Breezejs?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, breeze

I've been trying to test an angular app with Jasmine and they work pretty well. I'm also developing an Angular app based in John Papa's Hottowel.

But alas, the testing is impossible because BreezeJs doesn't seem to be testable at all. It keeps interfering in my testing and can't find a way to mock, stub or spy on it.

There are some old questions about the subject but the only answer seem to be promises from the otherwise brilliant Ward Bell.

It apparently can be tested, internally, with QUnit, but the tests are straightforward and no trace of how to work with other frameworks, let alone the leader in the market, Angular.

So, my question is: 
Does anybody know of a way to test Breezejs with Jasmine and Angular or should I forget the idea altogether and go with good old $http...?

Thanks from the obviously frustrated Miguel Delgado

Comment: Can you post a short piece of code you are trying to test?

Comment: Thanks Michal, the piece is below...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks to Bell Ward and PW Kad for their help.

As a way of illustration on how I "solved" the problem:

The issue is that the app is based on John Papa's Hottowel that has a method  called Prime that preloads lookups.

Because of this, any time the app runs, Breeze requests the metadata, the lookups and a lot of work is done at startup. Usually Breeze throws exceptions on empty metadata.

I'm not any good at TDD but my understanding is that the piece being tested has to be isolated of other "moving parts", so, all work done by Breeze should be abstracted or mocked.

Until today, I didn't know how to mock Breeze, I tried but the mocks were leaving holes for data expected by Prime and the default controller.

So, I did this:

```
    Boilerplate prep work... then:

    beforeEach(inject(function($injector, breeze) {

        // Set up the mock http service responses
        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');

        // backend definition common for all tests
        $httpBackend.when('GET', '/auth').respond(200, [{ id: 1, name: "banana" }]);
        $httpBackend.whenGET('breeze/Breeze/Metadata').respond(200, 
                         {THE WHOLE METADATA FILE GOES HERE!}

        //This are calls for each lookup
        $httpBackend.whenGET('breeze/Breeze/Lookup1?').respond(200, [{}]); //dummy answer,ok
        $httpBackend.whenGET('breeze/Breeze/Lookup2?').respond(200, [{}]);

        $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');

        var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');

        //The controller doesn't have anything to do with breeze...
        createController = function () {
            return $controller(authentication, { '$scope': $rootScope });
        };


       //...boilerplate Jasmine...
```

I had to insert the whole metadata file because it was unknown what would be needed at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Breeze apps are easy to test but I certainly agree that we lack sufficient guidance.

In the short run, you'll find a Breeze/Angular app with Jasmine tests [here in the Zza-Node-Mongo sample](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/tree/master/node/zza-node-mongo/client/test).

I'm working on a PluralSight course on testing Angular apps and hope to give it a breeze section. I'd love to have your specific questions soon so I can incorporate them (at least in my planning).

Comment: Thanks Ward... the sample really helped me... Apologize for the weenie tone of the note, clearly written in a moment of frustration. You are always brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily mock a breeze.js application using fake entities that are only loaded as a part of your tests.  Here is an article I wrote on the exact subject - http://pwkad.wordpress.com/2014/02/02/creating-mocks-with-breeze-js/ - that shows you how to get started.

Comment: **Nice!** That's a terrific leg up for the Breeze developer